# How to install specific extension version in visual studio

Tags: visual-studio-2013, visual-studio-extensions

I have updated an extension that visual studio said needed updating this morning "SQLite for Windows Phone". I have updated it from Version 3.8.6 to 3.8.7. Now a reference in my project is broken. I would like to roll this back to version 3.8.6. Is this possible?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I guess you can go to "Tools" > "Extensions and updates", search it in the "Installed" section and once selected click the "Uninstall" button.

Then download the .vsix installer of the 3.8.6 version (http://www.sqlite.org/2014/sqlite-wp80-winrt-3080600.vsix or similar) and double-click it to install.

FWIW, the .vsix is actually a .zip file so you can open it to check its contents if you want to be sure about what is going to install.

Comment: I would have thought there would be an easier way. But this method works. Why SQLite would update an extension without updating references in their nuget packages I don't know